# HyperV-2012R2 Storage Migration cannot migrate entire VM in FCM

Tags: hyper-v, storage, migration, live-migration

I am new to HyperV and currently moving our setup from esix4.1 to 2012R2 HyperV. We were testing out the storage migration and it is pretty cool but I could not figure this out:
- If the VM is not in a Fail Over cluster then we can initiate the migration from HyperV Manager, a wizard comes up and provides a way to move the entire VM (including vhdx etc.). This works fine

- If the VM is in a failover cluster then when you try to initiate the migration from HyperV-manager, it throws up an error saying you need to do this from FCM. Now, the FCM move provides a drag/drop interface and it only allows the VHDX file to be move and not the entire VM folder. So essentially the data moves over but the smaller files which actually make the VM work cannot be moved.

Am I missing something here or this is by design?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No you just drag the VM without expanding the VM(which lists the individual files) and it moves all the files for you.